# gstreamer pipeline to playback mp4 file on windows

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

video file is working perfectly with below pipeline.

```
.\gst-launch-1.0.exe playbin uri=file:///C:\\Users\\naseeb\\Downloads\\Gabbroo.mp4
```

But, i want to create pipeline myself using demux, decoder and sink.
I created below pipeline

```
.\gst-launch-1.0.exe filesrc location=C:\\Users\\naseeb\\Downloads\\Gabbroo.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! mad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demux. ! queue ! avdec_h264  ! autovideosink
```

but it is not working and failed with error mentioned below:

> WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux: Delayed linking > failed.
>   Additional debug info:
>   ./grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux:
>   failed delayed linking some pad of GstQTDemux named demux to some pad of GstQueue named queue0
>   Redistribute latency...
>   Redistribute latency...
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux: Internal data stream error.
>   Additional debug info:
>   qtdemux.c(5850): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux:
>   streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

I have searched lot and couldn't find what element i am missing in the pipeline to make it working.

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may need audio and video parsers before the decoders. So try `mpegaudioparse ! mad` and `h264parse ! avdec_h264`.
2. You most likely need a video converter between the decoder and the videosink. Try `autovideoconvert ! autovideosink`.

Comment: Now i get error: Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstQTDemux named demux to some pad of GstQueue named queue0
Redistribute latency...

Comment: Are you sure the file contains the streams you are trying to decode? Try `gst-discoverer-1.0 mp4file`.

Comment: Thanks Florian. gst-discoverer told me that mp4 file contains AAC audio. i used correct audio parser and decoder and can play the file properly now. I used the command:  .\gst-launch-1.0.exe filesrc location=C:\\Users\\naseeb\\Downloads\\Gabbroo.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! aacparse ! avdec_aac ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demux. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264  ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: `gst_parse_no_more_pads ()` Found any fix?